# Use hastag and php in fragment identifier

Tags: php, wordpress, anchor, href

I am trying to build a navbar that that list newest post and references to them via fragment identifier hyper link, as in:

```
<ul class="nav">

    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); ?>
    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
    <li class=""><a href="<?php the_title(); ?> "><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile;?>

</ul>
```

Further down on my page I have an anchor as in:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query ->have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<section id="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Problem is that when I add hastag before `<?php the_title(); ?>` things stop working..

Comment: _“Problem is that when I add hashtag […]”_ – where are you doing that?

Comment: I add hashtag before <?php the_title(); ?> so I get href="#<?php the_title(); ?>"

Comment: And then what’s “not working” and _how_ not? The title probably contains spaces and whatnot, and therefor does not make for a valid `id`. I’d suggest using the post _id_ instead as section id and hash value to link to the section (and prefix it with a letter for compatibility)

Comment: And I call that by: <?php get_the_ID(); ?> right?.... I get an empty string when I do though?

Comment: Got it working, had to use : <?php $this_page_id = $wp_query->post->ID; echo $this_page_id ;?>

Comment: Rather than `<?php $this_page_id = $wp_query->post->ID; echo $this_page_id ;?>`, you can get away with `the_id()`. `get_the_id()` returns the value without echoing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a way that work is:

```
<ul class="nav"><?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); ?>
                                <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="#post-<?php the_id(). get_the_id() ;?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endwhile;?>
                            </ul>
```

(got it from the comments above but figured I'd summarise so I can mark as solve)